# How to use surface snapping on a wireframe in 2.8?

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, snapping

In 2.7x we can snap to the surface of an object with max draw type set to wireframe:

[image]

However, as of [`81a7f6c848`](https://developer.blender.org/rB81a7f6c84844a7eafc33711c1fb792e8e0bbc459) this no longer works; the target object must have a solid draw type:

[image]

I like using a smooth subsurf'd "envelope" mesh to describe the general shape of an object, then snapping + shrinkwrapping bits on top of it to make details which couldn't easily be incorporated in the subsurf'd envelope mesh. While doing this, I have found having the envelope mesh in wireframe mode to be best for seeing what is going on.

Is there some way to get an equivalent behavior in 2.8, or an alternate workflow for detailing subsurf'd meshes?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about vert to face snapping in edit mode right? With the target having a max draw type of wireframe. I just tested in an old (january-ish) version of 2.8 and it appears to work there. I think you may have bug.

Comment: @Sazerac Yes, vert to face in edit mode, specifically with individual element snapping on. The version I tested on was quite recent, master at `fb7f157ff89d` Do you have the hash of the working version?

Comment: hash is c97c76c01c1d. Although looking at your screenshot, it may just be that snapping is not enabled? The magnet looks greyed out to me.

Comment: @Sazerac Ah, I was using Ctrl (you can be sure as it does work when Suzanne is solid). In hindsight I probably should've enabled it for gif visibility..

Comment: That makes sense. At a wild guess, I suspect this is a result of a developer switching from an internal format mesh raycast to an opengl call to get the surface to snap to.

Comment: @Sazerac I've managed to find [the commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB81a7f6c84844a7eafc33711c1fb792e8e0bbc459) which made the change; judging by the comment, it looks like it was intentional

Comment: That makes things tricky indeed. I guess snapping options probably needs another flag.